# Adding ASP.Net Button Event Handler at run-time is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, page-lifecycle

I need to add an event handler to 2 buttons programmatically and I can't get it to work. I've tried adding the event handlers at every stage of the Page Life Cycle I know of but the event never fires when the buttons are clicked. I have 2 buttons: btnEdit1 and btnEdit2. Here's my code:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            statusid = "2";
            assetid = "34";

            if (employeeid != null)
            {
                if (statusid == "3" || !SystemsManagementUtils.IsOwner(Convert.ToInt32(assetid), employeeid))
                {
                    btnEdit1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('You do not have permission to edit this item');");
                    btnEdit2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('You do not have permission to edit this item');");
                    btnDelete1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('You do not have permission to delete this item');");
                    btnDelete2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('You do not have permission to delete this item');");
                }
                else
                {
                    btnEdit1.Click += new EventHandler(btnEdit_Click);
                    btnEdit2.Click += new EventHandler(btnEdit_Click);
                    btnDelete1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:delItem(" + assetid + ");");
                    btnDelete2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:delItem(" + assetid + ");");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried this with OnPreInit() (doesn't work because the buttons don't yet exist), OnInit(), OnInitComplete(), OnPreLoad(), Page_Load(), OnLoadComplete(), OnPreRender(), and OnPreRenderComplete(). At no point does the event fire when one of the buttons is clicked, even though I've followed the code successfully to those lines in the debugger. I've tried commenting out the base.OnInit(e) line - I only added it because I saw it in an example. I'm not sure why I'd need it, but I'm desperate. Why is this not working?

Comment: You mean the click event of the button server-side, right? Not the click event in the browser?  Is that btnEdit1 a Button class (in the WebConrols namespace)

Comment: The Buttons do have a unique ID, right?

Comment: Yes, the click event of the button server-side, and yes, they have unique ID's.

Comment: Can you break in the Page_load and inspect the Request.Form property and check if the ID of that button appears in one way or the other in that Name propery of one of elements for the Form namevalue collection.

Comment: I don't see a namevalue collection for Request.Form, either in OnInit or in Page_Load.

Comment: That is strange. You did add the buttons somewhere so they end-up inside the `<form>` and `</form>` tag? I almost suspect that your code is fine but there is something wrong with the html that gets generated.

Comment: It's possible. I gave up and went at it another way: I set a global variable to indicate if the user was an owner or not. Then went the event is triggered, I checked the value of the variable. If they're an owner, something happens. If not, the javascript just pops up and gives them the "no permission" message. On to the next problem. Thanks for your time and thoughts, though, I appreciate it.